# Becomes double after taking half

Tags: riddle

What is the thing which becomes double after taking half? Please find out the thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible answers, in no particular order:

> * quadruple (remove half, and it becomes double)
>  * half an hour (remove "half" to get "an hour")
>  * double decker (remove the other 6-letter word, becomes "double")
>  * hurry (take half of the allowed time, and your hurry doubles)
>  * multiplication (remove multiplication by half, and the result doubles)

Or in other words, this may possibly be a bit too broad to fit the guidelines.

Answer (score 5):

One answer could be:

> The number 0. You can take half of zero, and it will still be zero, which is the double of zero.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

> Doubleheader. If you take half of the word it becomes double.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not quite right but how about

> A cell (organism)? When it splits in half you get two 'identidal' cells, they will be the same size as the original cell if you wait a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is correct, but:

> Time.  If you take away half the allotted time for an activity, you will need to "double time" to get it done.